# Can I insert my current configuration of grub and boot system Efi from Ubuntu in Kubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, grub-efi

I ask that question because my current pc is not very powerful, I have had problems with Ubuntu because it consumes too much cpu and does not use almost the RAM, my pc is going slow! That is why I would like to try flavors and I want to know if I can pass my current startup configuration and grub? because I don't want to go through the typical problems when starting a new installation, like "irq 1.55", which usually always happens to me XD!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you wondering if you can install kubuntu on your machine that currently has ubuntu, and then copy the grub configuration that took you a long time to get working?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new user. about the installation it will be on the same machine but on another new disk an SSD and I want to start there again, the problem was that trying to install a new distribution sent me an error, vector not supported! and architecture problems, that's why I want to know if I can insert my old EFI boot configuration (which already has all the settings of the pc), for example in a live cd and thus install without problems .. sorry I don't speak much English, no there are many people who speak it where I live XD ..

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: no.

A new installation on a different hard disk will require different parameters to work.  Unfortunately you can't simply copy it. Grub config files identify which disk to boot from, with a new disk the current config will not work without adjustments.

Your options are to save a copy of it and use it as a reference on things to try, once you have the new installation and start having issues, if that happens; or to copy it and make adjustments. But the adjustments needed will require knowledge that most new users don't have. If you're willing to invest the time and learn lots about grub and boot, you can try that.

I'm sorry, but I don't see any easy way for you. Either you'll have to possibly deal with the errors you dealt before, or you'll have to spend a lot of time learning about grub. If not both.